# Vsix (Visual Studio extension) full path of right-clicked file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, contextmenu, vsix

I would like to retrieve the full path of a right-clicked file (within the editor of Visual Studio 2017). I already implemented the following code to retrieve the path of a file when a project and/or solution is opened.

*This implementation isn't working if a single file is opened.*

**Scenario:**

1. Open VS (2017)
2. Navigate to File -> Open -> File.
3. Right click on a file and click on the desired context menu. (It calls the IsSingleProjectItemSelection method).
4. `monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierarchyPtr` fails, because `hierarchyPtr` remains IntPtr.Zero.

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: pUnk

Perhaps you know a solution to retrieve the full path of a right-clicked file within the editor of Visual Studio (2017)?

Thank you in advance.

```
    if (!IsSingleProjectItemSelection(out hierarchy, out itemid)) return;
        // Get the file path
        string itemFullPath = null;
        ((IVsProject) hierarchy).GetMkDocument(itemid, out itemFullPath);
        var transformFileInfo = new FileInfo(itemFullPath);    
        string fullPath = itemFullPath.FullName;

public static bool IsSingleProjectItemSelection(out IVsHierarchy   hierarchy, out uint itemid)
{
    hierarchy = null;
    itemid = VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL;
    int hr = VSConstants.S_OK;

    var monitorSelection = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellMonitorSelection)) as IVsMonitorSelection;
    var solution = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
    if (monitorSelection == null || solution == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    IVsMultiItemSelect multiItemSelect = null;
    IntPtr hierarchyPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr selectionContainerPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        hr = monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierarchyPtr, out itemid, out multiItemSelect, out selectionContainerPtr);

        if (ErrorHandler.Failed(hr) || hierarchyPtr == IntPtr.Zero || itemid == VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL)
        {
            // there is no selection
            return false;
        }

        // multiple items are selected
        if (multiItemSelect != null) return false;

        // there is a hierarchy root node selected, thus it is not a single item inside a project

        if (itemid == VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT) return false;

        hierarchy = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(hierarchyPtr) as IVsHierarchy;
        if (hierarchy == null) return false;

        Guid guidProjectID = Guid.Empty;

        if (ErrorHandler.Failed(solution.GetGuidOfProject(hierarchy, out guidProjectID)))
        {
            return false; // hierarchy is not a project inside the Solution if it does not have a ProjectID Guid
        }

        // if we got this far then there is a single project item selected
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (selectionContainerPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.Release(selectionContainerPtr);
        }

        if (hierarchyPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.Release(hierarchyPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName** returns full path of the file you right clicked in.