# Creating a Visual Studio menu command to get current active file path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, menu, .net-core, vsix

I am trying to create a 2017 VS extension with a button command that will display the file path of the current active file. I have followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2017#prerequisites and have already created the extention but I cannot seem to get the file path of the active file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47863101/84507

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (!IsSingleProjectItemSelection(out hierarchy, out itemid)) return;
    // Get the file path
    string itemFullPath = null;
    ((IVsProject) hierarchy).GetMkDocument(itemid, out itemFullPath);
    var transformFileInfo = new FileInfo(itemFullPath);    
    string fullPath = transformFileInfo.FullName;




public static bool IsSingleProjectItemSelection(out IVsHierarchy   hierarchy, out uint itemid)
{
    hierarchy = null;
    itemid = VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL;
    int hr = VSConstants.S_OK;

    var monitorSelection = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellMonitorSelection)) as 
    IVsMonitorSelection;
    var solution = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
    if (monitorSelection == null || solution == null)
    {
        return false;
    }        

    IVsMultiItemSelect multiItemSelect = null;
    IntPtr hierarchyPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr selectionContainerPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        hr = monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierarchyPtr, out itemid, out multiItemSelect, out selectionContainerPtr);

        if (ErrorHandler.Failed(hr) || hierarchyPtr == IntPtr.Zero || itemid == VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL)
        {
        // there is no selection
        return false;
        }

        // multiple items are selected
        if (multiItemSelect != null) return false;

        // there is a hierarchy root node selected, thus it is not a single item inside a project

        if (itemid == VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT) return false;

        hierarchy = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(hierarchyPtr) as IVsHierarchy;
        if (hierarchy == null) return false;

        Guid guidProjectID = Guid.Empty;

        if (ErrorHandler.Failed(solution.GetGuidOfProject(hierarchy, out guidProjectID)))
        {
            return false; // hierarchy is not a project inside the Solution if it does not have a ProjectID Guid
        }

        // if we got this far then there is a single project item selected
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (selectionContainerPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.Release(selectionContainerPtr);
        }

        if (hierarchyPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.Release(hierarchyPtr);
        }
    }
}
```